# VSTO Msproject: Lock Task

Tags: vsto, ms-project

I'm working on a small addin, when I click on a button, I'd like to set my remainig work and duration to 0 and locked my tasks
So I built something like that, my like function works but it's just to locked my tasks where I have a problem:

```
  foreach (MSProject.Task i_objTask in g_objProject.Tasks)
            {
                if (i_objTask.WBS.like(WbsIndex+"%"))
                {
                    i_objTask.RemainingWork = 0;
                    i_objTask.RemainingDuration = 0;
                    **Here I'd like to add something like : i_objtTask.Locked=true but this proprety doesn't exist****

                }
            }
```

Any idea of how could I do that?

Comment: FYI The `Locked` field is not a task object property but rather a PWA (Project Web App) field which is why you can't set it directly at the task level. It is only relevant in a PWA setting and has no bearing within the MS Project application.

Comment: But in the task sheet view, there is a locked field which is used to lock or not a task, allowing to edit timesheet with these tasks (or not)
So built a class like I did for the custom field and now it's working, I can lock my task with my addin

Comment: Right, the Locked field is to support timesheets which are part of PWA / Project Online and not part of the native application. Setting Locked = Yes will not prevent changes to the task _in the application_, it only prevents changes in the online timesheets.

Answer (score 1):

`Record Macro` (under the Developer ribbon) is handy for this stuff. Using it gets you:

```
SetTaskField field:="Locked", value:="Yes"
```

Unfortunately, you have to select & iterate through tasks on the Task Sheet to manipulate tasks' fields in this way. I haven't seen a Task object property that you can set directly to manipulate the locked state.